# How to auto-mount loop-devices with partitions

Tags: linux, block-device

I am testing some filesystem driver code and would like to do so outside of the kernel. The simplest and safest method for doing this is from userspace. So, I have created a file of some length

`dd if=/dev/zero of=testfs bs=10M count=50`

Then I installed an MBR partitioning scheme using fdisk

`fdisk testfs`

I can setup a loop device to access my file in block emulated mode:

```
$ losetup /dev/loop0 testfs
```

At this point I am able to see this new emulated block device in the device list:

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0    50G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0    46G  0 part /
├─sda2   8:2    0     1K  0 part 
└─sda5   8:5    0     4G  0 part [SWAP]
sr0     11:0    1  55.2M  0 rom  
loop0    7:0    0    50M  0 loop
```

And this device has the follow partition table

```
$ fdisk -l /dev/loop0 

Disk /dev/loop0: 52 MB, 52428800 bytes
96 heads, 25 sectors/track, 42 cylinders, total 102400 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0xe7d5af9a

      Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/loop0p1   *        2048      102399       50176    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
```

However, to create a fileyststem I need to mount the *partition*, not the "disk". Does the looping system not automatically mount the device's partitions, similar to the other block devices? I was able to create the filesystem by mounting the file through the loop at an offset

```
$ losetup -o $((2048*512)) /dev/loop0 testfs
```

But this solution is less than ideal since the behavior is slightly different than real block devices. Is there a way to "automount" partitions when doing through a loop device?

Answer (score 7):

There is an option for that:

```
losetup --partscan /dev/loop0 testfs
```

This will activate the regular partition support in your kernel, creating `/dev/loop0p1` and so on.

---

You can also use partx from util-linux:

```
losetup /dev/loop0 testfs
partx -u /dev/loop0
```

This will create kernel-based partitions (`/dev/loop0p1`, etc.), but the partition table itself will be parsed using libblkid, rather than asking the kernel.

---

Finally there is kpartx from multipath-tools:

```
losetup /dev/loop0 testfs
kpartx -u /dev/loop0
```

Although at first glance this is the same as above, it does not use the kernel's native loop-partition support at all. Instead it creates `/dev/mapper/loop0p1` using the device-mapper subsystem (linear mappings).

Comment: This detailed answer should have been accepted.